# A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script is invoked via document.write - how to circumvent it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, document.write

Google Chrome started implementing [Blocking the load of cross-origin, parser-blocking scripts inserted via document.write in the main frame](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/HGh92uMX_kE) on slow networks, which causes the following error:

> A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://example.org/script.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.

However, my web page requires loading a third party script synchronously, using `document.write('<script src="..."></script>')`. How to circumvent that blockade?

More about that change:

- [Design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dMJRQKTw75ZNdknP3pirSBH3koPl_IWHnxlcBuu4t_c/edit)
- [Longer document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AtS83d9joGj-xmt_pZB4Uvvn_9d1aEReRg0rI_5runw/edit)
- [Web Incubator CG issue](https://github.com/WICG/interventions/issues/17)
- [Chrome Issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=640844)

Comment: Why does it have to be via document.write?

Comment: @CBroe Because this is the script I got from a third-party and I am not authorized to change it (plus browsers should not suddenly break long-standing pages).

Comment: Well that 3rd party will need to modify their code they give out to customers anyway, if they want it to continue to work in browsers that implement this. So you should talk to them.

Comment: @CBroe What about web pages that are no longer updated? Browsers should load them as they always did, not break them.

Comment: Same problem, tried to add a ad script. But shows this error and the ads are not working. Anyone could help me regarding this ?

Comment: @CBroe my Wordpress google analytics dashboard plugin broke when this was implemented

Comment: @Rexford so what, then get it updated.

Comment: @CBroe get what updated? I don't own the plugin.

Comment: So the plugin author needs to update it. Again: So what? That happens all the time in the world of plugins.

Comment: @CBroe You don't mean (possibly) millions of websites should be updated or they will stop loading, do you? The main principle of the Internet has always been backward compatibility (back to the [first website](http://info.cern.ch/)) and now Google breaks it. Not nice.

Comment: @niutech: Backwards compatibility is a double-edged sword. Yes, we need it to a certain degree - but it can also easily become a hindrance to progress.

Comment: @CBroe, I had to laugh at your comment to Rexford regarding the google analytics dashboard.  Do you not see the irony there?  Google broke their own plugin!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write), you can:

- Use asynchronous script loading, using `<script src="..." async>` or `element.appendChild()`,
- [Submit the script provider to Google for whitelisting](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdMQ7PfoVMob5OTXSgodoG5V1eNC5CyQ_qo4skbN62RDSEPcg/viewform).

Comment: Are you sure that submission link is genuine, I was just about to fill it in when I noticed it's just a Google Form that someone has created, and has spelling and grammar mistakes all over it... Doesn't look genuine.

Comment: @Lee That link appears in the official [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write#how_do_i_fix_this) above.

Comment: Using asynchronous scripts means that your page can render more quickly. Instead of forcing users to wait for a script to finish downloading before the page renders, a script can be downloaded in the background.

Although most scripts were originally synchronous, newer versions of the scripts have been designed to load asynchronously.  Check https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseAsync

Comment: Mangesh: some scripts must be loaded synchronously (e.g. if another script depends on the first one).

Comment: I've faced this issue today and adding "async" did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @nuitech Is there a way to do this and still load all my scripts synchronously?  I have second script that is dependent on certain things loading from the first one.  When I do the above solutions `async` or `element.appendChild()` the first script gets delayed being loaded causing errors in the 2nd script.

Answer (score 19):

@niutech
I was having the similar issue which is caused by **Rocket Loader Module** by Cloudflare.
Just disable it for the website and it will sort out all your related issues.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the Rocket Loader Module of Cloudflare, which is in beta. If there are more people submitting it to be [whitelisted by Google](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdMQ7PfoVMob5OTXSgodoG5V1eNC5CyQ_qo4skbN62RDSEPcg/viewform) it might help

Comment: This happens to me on the first access to my site's url and is associated with the activation of the Rocket Loader module indeed, but it is a pitty if I have to disable it, because it gave me some good points on google page insights. Any other option?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes Rocket Loader Module is in Beta at this stage. Need to wait until Cloudflare update it and launch it as Stable version.

Or as an alternative, you use niutech's answer.

Comment: Thanks, if someone is wondering as I was, the Rocket Loader Module is in the Speed section on Cloudflare.

Comment: Rocket Loader is no longer showing up as in beta. Seems to be now in production. The help section says to add data-cfasync="false" to the <script> attributes to have Rocket Loader ignore that specific script. Adding the attribuite did not work for my case. Disabled Rocket Loader to fix this issue. Thanks @VaibhavMistry

Answer (score 4):

Don't use document.write, here is workaround:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  
script.src = "....";  
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Many times you cannot modify a third-party script which is using `document.write`.

Comment: @niutech I think all listed solutions are trying to change sync loading to async, but you are asking for loading 3rd-party script synchronously, then I'm thinking it may be hard to get a solution if the 3rd-party script is using document.wrtie. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Or put the 3rd-party script in the same domain of your script may resolve this issue. This solution need handle the synchronization between local copy and original copy.