# Chrome blocking script invoked with document.write() - how to test

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This stack overflow describes the issue where Chrome will block scripts that are invoked with document.write if the user is on 2G ([A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script is invoked via document.write - how to circumvent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610829/a-parser-blocking-cross-origin-script-is-invoked-via-document-write-how-to-ci))

According to the Google dev page (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write) - "When a script inserted via document.write has been blocked, Chrome will send the following header to the requested resource:"

```
Intervention: <https://shorturl/relevant/spec>;
```

The article states "You can enable "2G" mode in Chrome DevTools, however in Chrome 55 it doesn't properly trigger the intervention. The best option is to enable this intervention using chrome://flags/#disallow-doc-written-script-loads.". I have enabled the "Block scripts loaded via document.write" flag as well as set my network throttling to "Regular 2G", however still do not see this flag being set in the request header. It appears to be executing the script as expected.

Is there something that I am missing to get this header set?

I am using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though this flag is only being passed on the beta version of Chrome currently. It's working as described when testing on the beta (Version 55.0.2883.44 beta (64-bit))